# Undefined local variable/method User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning how to seed data into my project using the faker gem currently. My project is a todo list that allows users to checkoff and add items. I learned how to create my own RandomData but I'm having trouble adapting a gem into the tutorial.  I also am not sure if I'm 'adapting' this to the tutorial correctly so I hope I provide enough information.

When running `rake db:reset` error is as follows:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
itoff/db/seeds.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
itoff/db/seeds.rb:11:in `times'
itoff/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
```

I see that it's in my fake items loop, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Keep in mind I'm very new at Ruby on Rails, so my apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Using devise and faker gems.

(Question at the end: What can I do better?  What else should I work/focus on to get better at ruby on rails?)

**seeds.rb**:

```
#Create fake user
5.times do
  user = User.new(
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
  )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
end

#Create fake items
10.times do
  item = Item.create!(
    user: user.sample,
    name: Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{User.count} users created"
puts "#{Item.count} items created"
```

my **items_controller.rb**:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      redirect_to current_user, notice: "Item was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating item. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end


  def destroy
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])

     if @item.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "\"#{@item.name}\" was deleted successfully."
       redirect_to action: :index
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the item."
       render :show
     end
   end

  private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

**item.rb**:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

**user.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

         has_many :items
end
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, can you post the new errors you have?

Comment: yes! Sorry I've been extremely busy with school work.  Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. There error is because your `user` variable in the `seeds.rb` file is out of scope. It is inside of a `do` block. Moreover, you should user the `User` class, not an instance:

```
5.times do
  user = User.new( # This is inside of a do block
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
  )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
end

#Create fake items
10.times do
  item = Item.create!(
    user: user.sample, # Which user? There is no user in this scope
    name: Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end
```

What you need to do is call `.sample` on the `User` class; however, you can't just pluck a user that way. You need to grab a random `id`:

```
#Create fake items
user_ids = User.ids # See the capitalization of User
10.times do
  item = Item.create!(
    user_id: user_ids.sample,
    name: Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end
```

Alternatively to grabbing an `id` out of all of the `id`s. You can do this: `User.order("RANDOM()").first`, and that will grab a random `User` model. This would be:

```
#Create fake items
10.times do
  item = Item.create!(
    user: User.order("RANDOM()").first
    name: Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end
```

Comment: Yes, Dbz answer is touching on the issue. When you are trying to create a new item, the user is out of scope. So, to fix this, you need to change user: user.sample for user_id: User.ids.sample (I am guessing this is the name of this column since you are using it as a foreign key).